# Incoming call receiver is not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

I am developing an android application to detect missed calls and I have attached all of my codings below

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>


 <receiver android:name="com.mypackage.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter></receiver>
```

MyReceiver.java :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 

{

            String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            Toast.makeText(context,"Incoming call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(state==null)
            {
                 Toast.makeText(context,"Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 return;
            }

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
             {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Call received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                      
             }

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(context,"Idle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


}}
```

Additionally I have two activities in my project (One Main Activity). I think the code is perfect and clean. But it is not working. My Receiver is not detecting any incoming calls since Toast is not displayed while getting a  call.That means onReceive() method is not called at all while receiving an incoming call.

I have already tried various solutions suggested in Stackoverflow to the same question asked before long.. But nothing is solved my problem..

If someone suggest a solution, it wil be more helpful...

Comment: Have you defined your receiver in your manifest?

Comment: Just nw edited d post. Sorry for inconvenience..

Comment: Have you given the correct path for your MyReceiver class in receivers manifest ie "com.mypackage.MyReceiver"

Comment: Yes.. i have given d correct path....

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your intent filter closing tag. 
You have used `</intent-filter/>` where as it should be `</intent-filter>`. Their is an extra / for closing the tag. Changed code -

```
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>


    <receiver android:name="com.mypackage.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```